# Stock Price Differences Between TD Ameritrade, WeBull, Public

Tags: stocks, price, comparison

Why is TD Ameritrade stock price always the lowest compared to WeBull or even Public at the exact same time? Example, AMC stock was $55.34 on WeBull vs $55.17 on TD Ameritrade. I have noticed regardless of which stock you are considering, TD Ameritrade is mostly lower, why is this?

Comment: To get a better answer to the question, look also at the price quoted by other big brokerages, and other FinTech brokerages.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the second tier brokers average the bid and the ask when they provide a quote.

It's also possible that Ameritrade's server updates their quotes a tad faster than WeBull.

Comment: Why do some second tier brokers average the bid and ask instead of showing the price of the last trade?

Comment: Because they're Mickey Mouse operations?  Because it costs less to do so?  I can only guess.